# Wait for an asynchronous method inside a synchronous method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, deferred

Here is the situation :

I have 2 JS functions, and I need to wait these 2 methods to do other things.
So I've written :

```
$.when(foo1(), foo2()).done(function () {
    //do something
});
```

This works well.

However, in some cases `foo2()` must load a partial view in my DOM :

```
function foo2() {
    $("#bar").load('/controller/action')
}
```

It seems that the code inside the `.done` callback is executed at the end of `foo1()` and `foo2()` *whereas the partial view is not fully loaded*.

How can I say to `foo2()` to wait for the end of the partial view loading, before to say "Ok I finished my job, you can continue" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `load()` doesn't return a promise or deferred object. Instead, to make this work you could manually return a deferred object from `foo2()` which you resolve after the `load()` completes. Something like this:

```
function foo2() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred()
  $("#bar").load('/controller/action', function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  });
  return deferred;
}
```

Comment: To future proof, since ECMA has deprecated the `var defer = Promise.defer()` syntax (and I imagine jQuery will eventually follow suit), it might be better to use the proper Promise syntax: `function foo2() { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { $("#bar").load('/controller/action', () => { resolve(); }); }); }`;

Comment: It seems it's working, thank you ! I'll try @Jpec07 syntax to check it out

Comment: @Jpec07 that depends entirely on browser support needed.  Promise isn't supported in IE 11.  And arrow functions definitely are not supported in IE11.

Comment: Good to know. A quick search shows that IE11's lifecycle is tied to Windows 7, and Microsoft is cutting support for that in 2020. So until then, `$.Deferred()` seems like the way to go.